# Is there a limit to the number data extensions you can have in MC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

As the title suggests is there a hard limit to the number of data extensions that can be created in a Marketing Cloud instance? (not the storage, just the number of DE's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices would be to add [retention settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_manage_de_policies.htm&type=5) on DEs to get rid of the DE when it is no longer needed. Also this [dev doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/optimizing_api_calls_and_data_structures_to_improve_performance_in_the_salesforce_marketing_cloud.htm) lists some general guidelines:

> Optimum Thresholds
>
> While each account differs depending on the amount of data stored and the processes performed, the table below outlines some general thresholds around common practices.
>
> The Normal column indicates optimum operation for the listed entity.
>   The Aggressive column indicates that your calls could encounter performance issues.
>   The Extreme column indicates significant performance degradation that requires immediate remediation.
>
> Entity Normal  Aggressive  Extreme
>
> Concurrent Imports to a Data Extension 1   2   3 or more
>
> Concurrent Imports to Lists    1   2   3 or more
>
> Data Extensions in an Account  0-1000  1000-10000  >10000